# reading the value of an array of json and putting it into set through java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson library with java 11 so basically I am able to read the below JSON into a string format

```
{

   "schemas":[
      "urn:params:core:2.0:User",
      "urn:params:core:3.0:User"
   ],
     },

}
```

here below is the set in which I have to fill the values of schemas from above json

```
private Set<String> setschemas = null;
```

right now I am able to read the above json into a string named finaljson , now please advise how can I read the differnt value of schemas from above json string named finaljson and set it to set named setschemas

```
if (node.has("schemas")) {
    // *** here I want to read the differernt value of schemas and set it to a set
    // named setschemas
    // *****
}
```

Comment: Do you know the structure of the json ? If so, you can create classes that would correspond to your json to deserialize it automatically with jackson.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the following classes that represent the json structure

```
class MyJsonObject {

    private AppIdentity appIdentity;
    private Set<String> schemas;
    private String userName;

}

class AppIdentity {
    private String clientId;
    private String username;
}
```

than you can use 
`final MyJsonObject myJsonObject = new ObjectMapper().readValue(finaljson, MyJsonObject.class);` to read the json to JAVA object

so it can manipulated like `myJsonObject.schemas.size() > 0` and such...

there are a lot of examples in the internet

*keep in mind, this solution only works when the json structure and fields name are known in advanced

Answer (score 0):

With your approach, this would be simplest one:

```
if(node.has("schemas")) {
        JsonNode schemaNode = node.get("schemas");
        Set<String> schemaSet = objectMapper.convertValue(schemaNode, Set.class);
        System.out.println("schemaSet" + schemaSet);
}
```

There are various ways to deal with JSON one is described here

1) You can create a class of JSON structure as follows with help online JSON to POJO convertor (Note:: Add Setters and Getters with help of IDE)

```
class AppJson {
    private Set<AppIdentity> appIdentity;
    private Set<String> schemas;
    private String userName;
    private Manager ManagerObject;
    private String division;
    private String organization;
    private String costCenter;
    private String employeeNumber;
}

class AppIdentity {
    private String clientId;
    private String username;
}

class Manager {
    private String value;
    private String $ref;
    private String displayName;
    private String $Ref;
}
```

2) Use above for object conversion.

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = "{\"appIdentity\":[{\"clientId\":\"9a41763c642\",\"username\":\"XXX\"}],\"schemas\":[\"urn:params:core:2.0:User\",\"urn:params:core:3.0:User\"],\"userName\":\"ajklmnop_699100\",\"manager\":{\"value\":\"string\",\"$ref\":\"sdkoirk\",\"displayName\":\"string\",\"$Ref\":\"sdkweoirk\"},\"division\":\"string\",\"organization\":\"string\",\"costCenter\":\"string\",\"employeeNumber\":\"string\"}\n"
            + "";
    AppJson appJson = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, AppJson.class);
    System.out.println("json " + appJson.getSchemas());
```

Here you will get the schemas.